# Currency range and format validator for string field

Tags: c#, data-annotations

What are correct currency data annotations for the following condition?

1. Numeric amount with 2 decimal places.
2. Minimum amount $1.00; max amount $25000.00

Here is my field.

```
public string amount {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the decimal places you can use the RegularExpression annotation with the proper regex to match your number format:

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\.\d{2}){1}$")]
```

To check for the Minimum and Maximum value we must create our own **Custom Attributes**

```
[MinDecimalValue(1.00)]
[MaxDecimalValue(25000.00)]
public string amount { get; set; }
```

We can do this by creating a class deriving from **ValidationAttribute** and overriding the **IsValid** method.

See my implementation below.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class MaxDecimalValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private double maximum;
        public MaxDecimalValueAttribute(double maxVal)
            : base("The given value is more than the maximum allowed.")
        {
            maximum = maxVal;
        }
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var stringValue = value as string;
            double numericValue;
            if(stringValue == null)
                return false;
            else if(!Double.TryParse(stringValue, out numericValue) ||  numericValue > maximum)
            {
                return false;
            }
        return true;
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MinDecimalValueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private double minimum;
    public MinDecimalValueAttribute(double minVal)
        : base("The given value is less than the minimum allowed.")
    {
        minimum = minVal;
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var stringValue = value as string;
        double numericValue;
        if (stringValue == null)
            return false;
        else if (!Double.TryParse(stringValue, out numericValue) || numericValue < minimum)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can read more on how to create your own attributes, also this code needs more improvement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this takes cares of $ in the front of the value?

Comment: I forgot about that. You can modify the regex expression annotation to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the Culture info class which follows the [link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)